# Extracting values by doing Lookup(vlookup/hlookup) in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup, lookup

These are columns of my table

```
**Type**                **long_name**       
route                    unamed road
locality                 yorkshire
sub-locality             printon
admin_area_level1        phase-II
PostalCode               490029
street_number            18
route                    JC park
neighborhood             behind A- Cabin
Sub-locality             leston k
Sub-locality1            park A
Sub-locality2            St Ben
locality                 Breach Candy
admin_area_level_2       Dun Street
admin_area_level_1       Parkton
country                  USSR
postal_code              587644
```

I want to look up the columns horizontally using HLOOKUP or any other lookup method, so that my output would become

```
#Street_number  #route          #intersection      #country    #admin_area_level_1 
NA             unamed road    NA                NA         phase-II  
18             JC Park        NA                USSR       Parkton
#admin_area_level_2    #admin_area_level_3    #locality     #ward    #sub-locality     
NA                    NA                    yorkshire    NA      NA   
Dun Street            NA                    Breach Candy NA     leston k 
#premises    #PostalCode
NA          490029
NA          587644
```

For this i tried using a HLOOKUP but tha seems doesn't working, it's giving All values as **#NA**

```
=HLOOKUP(Sheet1!J1,'sheet2'!I:J,2,FALSE)
```

Any Suggestion on how this should be done.Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your output? I'm not quite sure what you're needing as the output.  Also, perhaps look into `Index/Match`?

Answer (score 0):

Within this answer some issues are raised about the rules followed by the input data. These points could have been raised in a comment but would have seriously run into the 500 character limit.

The picture below shows the input data and the list of columns required in the output.

[image: Input Data and Columns for Output]

Ignore for the moment column `E` and columns `G:H` in this picture - I will come back to them later.

The values in column `D` of the input table (labelled `Rec.No`), represent the record number of the output table into which the `Long_name` value will be inserted. I have manually inserted values into this column. I will return to the automatic calculation of these values later.

Given the `Rec.No` values it is possible to calculate the output table as shown below.

[image: Calculated Output Table]

In both pictures cells shown in blue are formulae.

There are, no doubt, different ways of doing this Output calculation and I have used the following approach.

1. I have manually assigned each row of the Output table with a record number (labelled `Rec. No.`) in column `J`.
2. Columns `K` and `L` are a couple of helper columns. Column `K` (labelled `Starts`) identifies which row of data within the Input Data (see first picture) provides the initial row for the current Output record. Column `L` (labelled `Num.Rows`) indicates how many rows of the input table contribute to the current output record. The formula in cell `K4` is `=MATCH(J4,D$4:D$19,0)` whilst that in `L4` is `=COUNTIF(D$4:D$19,J4)`.
3. The helper column values are used within two `OFFSET()` functions to define ranges within columns `B` (labelled `Type`) and `C` (labelled `Long_name`) of the Input Data corresponding to each Output record. For the first Output record these ranges are `OFFSET($B$3,$K4,0,$L4,1)` and `OFFSET($C$3,$K4,0,$L4,1)` and they correspond to `$B$4:$B$8` and `$C$4:$C$8`, respectively - i.e. the parts of columns `B` and `C` for those rows where the `Rec.No` in column `D` is 1.
4. In cell `M4`, a `MATCH()` function is used to identify where the heading in cell `M3` occurs within the range of `Type` values defined by the first `OFFSET()` (range `$B$4:$B$8`). The result is used within an `INDEX()` function involving the second `OFFSET()` range (`$C$4:$C$8`) to identify the `Long_name` value matching to the heading. The formula in cell `M4` is
   `=INDEX(OFFSET($C$3,$K4,0,$L4,1),MATCH(M$3,OFFSET($B$3,$K4,0,$L4,1),0))` The formula returns `#N/A` if the heading in `M3` is not matched.
5. The formula in `K4` can be copied to `K5`, that in `L4` to `L5` and that in `M4` to `M4:X5`.

There are a couple of data issues to note:

- cell`D7` in the input has been corrected to `admin_area_level_1` (from `admin_area_level1`) and cell `D8` to `postal_code` (from `PostalCode`) to ensure consistency between the Input Data and the headings used in the Output.
- the results in the `sub-locality` for the first record of the Output have been calculated as `printon` (see cell `V4`) rather than the `NA` specified in the OP. The calculated result seems to be better aligned with the Input Data.

So far so good, but everything above has been dependent on the manually inserted values in the `Rec.No` column of the Input Data. If the approach is to be extended to larger input data sets - too large to contemplate manual assignment of this column - then there are some problems to be dealt with.

First, the number of rows of Input Data is clearly not the same for each record of the Output, so an approach based on simple counting cannot be used to assign the `Rec.No` column.

Second, returning to the first picture, column `E` labelled `Col.No` shows which column of the Output is matched to by the `Type` value. The columns of the Output are listed for convenience in the table in columns `G:H` and the formula in cell `E4` is `=MATCH(B4,$H$4:$H$15,0)`. This `Col.No` column shows that the ordering of `Type` values in the Input Data is different from the ordering of these values in the Output. For example, in the Output column `locality` occurs several columns after (to the right of) column `admin_area_level_1`, whereas in the Input Data `Type` value `locality` occurs **before** the value `admin_area_level_1`. This means it is not possible to use an approach based on assuming that the order of `Type` values in the Input Data follows the order of the Output column headings.

In fact, without the benefit of the output specified in the OP it is impossible to identify whether row 6 of the Input Data, with its `Type` value of `street_number` actually belongs to the first or second record of the Output.

What is missing from the OP is information about what rules are followed within the input data both in terms of the ordering of the `Type` values
and any rules on mandatory/optional types. Until those rules are more clearly specified, it will be impossible, in the general case, to implement a solution automatically.